# IIS version 10 with an application server to run JSP/Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, iis

It's old school JSP pages that I need to run via IIS using any application server.

I'm running windows 10 with latest IIS.

In those days if you request `http://localhost/product.jsp`, the application server would compile it into a servlet and run it and if i update jsp It'd recompile and run again.

Although things have changed recently (war deployment etc.) but what can I do to make these pages run?

It doesn't have to be IIS, all I care is to be able to run plain vanilla JSP.

Thanks

Comment: If you are not stuck with IIS, just use Tomcat, put your jsp in a folder inside  webapp folder and vuola ;-)

Comment: ok, I guess I've to run tomcat manually, have installed, is there a command to run in the cmd?

Comment: I see tomcat8.exe, and tomcat8w.exe in the bin folder

Comment: ok wait .. I am writing a full answer for tomcat...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as you are not insisting on using IIS, you can use tomcat.

You can download windows installler [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi).

In that case you could run tomcat as a service and easily stop and start it.

If you download **zip** version you should unpack it and run `catalina start` from command line form inside `bin` folder. (also `catalina stop` to stop it).

By the way I am assuming that you have `java` installed on your machine.

Jsp files go to a folder that you will create  inside  webapp folder (YourFolder).

Default port is **8080**

So the url will be http://localhost:8080/YourFolder/product.jsp

Hope this helps.

Comment: bravo. It works. one more thing I didn't ask though, how do I work out mysql JDBC drivers for tomcat

Comment: stop tomcat. put your drivers inside lib directory of the tomcat. start tomcat. ... also don't forget to accept and upvote ;-) I am glad to hear that it works ;-)

Comment: awesome, I'm just going to test mysql, what's the catalina command for? I mean I could run the command start directly.

Comment: `catalina start` - starts tomcat from command line. You use it mainly in zip version ... it sets up the environment, first checks some variables and then starts tomcat....(catalina is actually `catalina.bat`)